# Eclipse CDT Mars - "Dark Theme" is not completely dark

Tags: themes, ubuntu-14.04, x86-64, eclipse-mars

I've just downloaded Eclipse CDT Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), which ships with its own "Dark Theme". I've activated the theme but my IDE does not become completely dark.

This was also the case with the scroll-bars but I managed to override the color with the following environmental variable:

```
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1
```

I've searched for some information in the internet and found some suggestions involving the setting of the following environmental variables:

```
SWT_GTK3=0
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

I've also found some suggestions about the installation of gtk2/3 engines via:

```
apt-get install gtk2-engines-* gtk3-engines*
```

Unfortunately none of this worked in my case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same in 15.10. Worse, when a dialog is open the background of all the icons on the main window turns white /sigh